# how to use contexts in SAX XML parsing in C++(using libxml2)?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2, saxparser

I'm writing an xml parser application in C++ using libxml2 library. I use **startElementNsSAX2Func** to parse the elements and **charactersSAXFunc** to parse element values.

Signatures:

```
void    startElementNsSAX2Func  (void * ctx, const xmlChar * localname, const xmlChar * prefix, const xmlChar * URI, int nb_namespaces, const xmlChar ** namespaces, int nb_attributes, int nb_defaulted, const xmlChar ** attributes)
void    charactersSAXFunc(void * ctx, const xmlChar * ch, int len)
```

I want to make use of the **ctx** variable so that I can parse the xml document based on the order of the elements and I'm not sure how to do it. Any insight on this would be really helpful.

Also I couldn't find a good article on XML SAX parsing in C/C++. Does anyone know a good tutorial on this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ctx` argument of the SAX callbacks will hold the pointer that is passed as `user_data` to initialization functions like `xmlCreatePushParserCtxt` or `xmlCreateIOParserCtxt`:

```
xmlParserCtxtPtr xmlCreatePushParserCtxt (xmlSAXHandlerPtr sax, 
                                          void * user_data, 
                                          const char * chunk, 
                                          int size, 
                                          const char * filename)
```

It can be used to pass a pointer to an arbitrary user-defined structure. This structure will typically contain a state variable that can be used to determine the current position in the document tree.

A nice tutorial can be [found here](http://www.jamesh.id.au/articles/libxml-sax/libxml-sax.html). It uses the deprecated SAX1 interface, but the SAX2 interface is similar.